# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function - Error al cargar DataTable

Tags: jquery, laravel, bootstrap, datatables

Tengo el siguiente error al momento de inicializar un datatable, por lo que entiendo es como que si el jquery se cargara múltiples veces y por eso el error, pero si logran ver exactamente en la consola me remite al app.js, he cargado hasta por CDN jquery, las librerías de datatable y Bootstrap también.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejo tambien el codigo de mi datatable, por si alguien tiene alguna idea de que puede ser el problema:

```
    $(document).ready( function () {
    $('#table_id').DataTable({
        
        ajax: {
    url: "https://admindev.americaprays.org/api/contacts"
     
            },
        columns: [
        { data: 'name' },
        { data: 'last_name' },
        { data: 'id_church' },
        { data: 'zipcode.city.name' },
        { data: 'phone' },
        { data: 'email' },
        { data: 'zipcode.zip' }
     
                     ]
    });
} );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El orden en los script js son muy importantes , si usas Datatables procura que primero este jquery y debajo el datatables , te dejo [aqui](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html) un ejemplo de la pagina oficial de datatables en la cual muestra un ejemplo , y veas el orden de los archivos, procura hacerlo de la misma manera . Saludos